# Can I configure docker buildx build to use the --load option by default?

Tags: docker-build, docker-buildkit, buildx

I have a bunch of shell scripts that run `docker build` to build Docker images, something like

```
#!/bin/bash

docker build -t my.registry/image1:latest dir1
docker build -t my.registry/image2:latest dir2
...
```

These images need to run on a `linux/amd64` machine.  Previously the Docker images were built on  `linux/amd64` machines, but now I need to additionally be able to build these images on an M1 MacBook (ARM64) as well.  Is there a way to configure and use a Buildx builder on my MacBook so that these scripts can be run there without change?  I found that I can configure a Buildx builder to only compile for `linux/amd64` and can alias `docker build` to `docker buildx build`:

```
docker buildx create --platform linux/amd64 --name mybuilder
docker buildx use mybuilder
docker buildx install
```

but I still need to specify the `--load` option.  Is there a way to configure that as a default as well or do I just have to update the scripts (and require Linux users to install Buildx)?

I've looked through various documentation pages with no luck, so it may not be possible but I just want to make sure I'm not missing something.